# Npm Start not running node.js, not running scripts

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am setting up a project with node & express. I am running the same error message.
I've read multiple help articles suggesting to clear the cache and create new .json files. I've also edited the scripts in the package.json file and had no luck clearing the error.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! package@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the package@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: please share your package json, the error does not seem to be npm related

Comment: posted a solution did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script is running `node ./bin/www` so do you have those folders and index.js file inside the directory?

Share your package.json and maybe it will give more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used [express generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to generate boiler code, to to test code in this case.

for macos

```
DEBUG=yourprojectfoldername:* npm start
```

for windows

```
set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start
```